# Proxypass error for different destination URL

Tags: apache2, proxypass

I have enabled proxypass setting for  subversion apache server.

Its working fine for below setting. Also able to checkout the repository.

```
ProxyPass  /svn/testing_migration  https://example.com/svn/testing_migration/

ProxyPassReverse /svn/testing_migration https:/example.com/svn/testing_migration/
```

When i pass for the different server which contain different path, I am getting error while checkout the repo. below are the setting

```
ProxyPass /svn/testing_migration https://example.com/svn/testing_migration/svn/repos/testing_migration/  

ProxyPassReverse /svn/testing_migration https:/example.com/svn/repos/testing_migration/
```

The above setting working fine when i access repository through browser but getting error while checkout the repo.

Error:URL isn't the same

Answer (score 1):

**Match trailing slashes always.**

You can find unexpected behaviour while reverse proxying when you do not add the necessary trailing slashes.

"Rule of thumb" is if there is trailing slash in source, so it should be in target, and the opposite also applies, if there is no trailing slash in source theere shouldn't be in target.

I would also add if target is / or example.com a trailing slash should always be specified in source and target to avoid mismatches.